# How to end the `i` command in GNU sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, stream, gnu-sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to make several substitutions and insertions of an input string.

However, I recently noticed that the insert command `i` doesn't terminate on `;` like others, and instead prints the rest of the string.

```
$ sed "s/^foo/bar/; 1i foo foo foo; s/foo$/baz/;"
```

When running that command on the following input,

```
foo bar baz
```

I get the following incorrect output.

```
foo foo foo; s/foo$/baz/;
bar bar baz
```

What's the correct way to terminate that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use multiple `-e` separated queries in a single command:

```
sed -e 's/^foo/bar/' -e '1i foo foo foo' -e 's/foo$/baz/' <<< "foo bar baz"
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/yUYoLw). Output:

```
foo foo foo
bar bar baz
```